# Can not run testNG.xml after upgrading intellij

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, testng, testng.xml

Today I updated intelij to the latest version from 2020.2 to 2020.3

In the previous version I could run the testng xml, by pressing right click and run.
After the update I could not fing it anymore,
how can I run testng.xml in intelij the new version?
regards (provided pic of before and after the update)
before the update

[image]

after the update

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256816

And it fixed in  `2020.3.1` Update your ide.